# media queries bootstrap set minimum responsive size will go?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So using the following code with template I can set when responsive mode kicks in.

```
@media all and (max-width: 680px)
```

However is there a query that if the browser width goes below for ex. 380px responsive, items stop minimizing etc. and stay at what would appear at 380px responsive only. So if someone was minimizing browser or had viewport of 280 they would be viewing what it looks like at 380px responsive but with scroll bars?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set a [**`min-width`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) on the `body` element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vYCk6/)

```
body {
    min-width:380px;
}
```

Comment: Great thank you..tested with css and works. So simple should have thought of that lol but was focusing on @media.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't offer that level of control but you can simple add the following media query and then impose styles on elements on screen sizes smaller than 380px wide.

```
@media all and (max-width: 379px) {
    // Style elements specifically for screen sizes less than 380px
}
```